# SSIS Download Azure Blob Connection Error

Tags: azure, ssis

I'm thrilled to be working on an SSIS project that will (hopefully) get deployed to Data Factory.  While getting my SSIS job setup, I added  a step to download files from Azure Blob Storage.  After adding a Azure Blob Download task, in the control flow, and entering in the storage configuration (test worked successfully), I get the following errors:

```
SSIS package "C:\....\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The connection "{27A6966C-8398-4C75-84C3-6007B96EEED4}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The connection "{27A6966C-8398-4C75-84C3-6007B96EEED4}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The connection "{27A6966C-8398-4C75-84C3-6007B96EEED4}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC0024102 at Azure Blob Download Task: The Validate method on the task failed, and returned error code 0x80131500 (The connection "{27A6966C-8398-4C75-84C3-6007B96EEED4}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
). The Validate method must succeed and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Azure Blob Download Task: There were errors during task validation.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (10) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\....Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[18968] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have confirmed that the GUID here is indeed pointing to the Azure Blob Connection in the XML.  I've recreated this problem on a couple of PCs, and I've deleted and recreated the connection and the Download Blob task dozens of times. 
 I'm not sure how to fix, or to get more information on the problem.  For what it's worth, this error pops up very soon after launching in Debug mode - only some pre-validation runs (successfully) prior to this error.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing a *complete* uninstall of all instances of visual studio and SSDT, and the Azure Feature Pack. Then after a reinstallation of these software instances - my blob features in SSIS worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment just yet so I have to answer your question. I haven't used an Azure Blob Connection but anytime I get that value of GUID it means the value it was expecting doesn't exist anymore. So lets say you set a source with your Azure Data Connection then you deleted the connection manager. Now the SSIS package can't find the associated connection manager. This will cause immediate errors.

I can give you a visual example if need be.

Comment: I do fully understand, however I have verified that the GUIDs do indeed exist in the underlying XML of the SSIS package.  I do believe that this is a problem with the Azure Feature Pack for SSIS, I can't get the Azure Blob Source to work either.

Comment: I ended up doing a complete uninstall of all instances of visual studio and SSDT, and the Azure Feature Pack.  Then after a reinstallation - this worked.